# Highcharts has missing markers at the top for very specific heights

Tags: highcharts

I'm seeing some weird behavior in highcharts 4.0.4, where line markers are missing for points on the topmost line, but only in specific cases.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fwL8t96g/1/

The highcharts config array is relatively simple,

```
config = {
    chart: {
        height: 250,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''  
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 100
    },
    series: [{
        data: [null,null,null,93,100,100,100,36,93,100,null,100]
    }]
};
```

The three charts in my link are almost exactly the same, except they have heights of 250, 251, and 249 respectively. Depending on which browser I use, sometimes the dots on the 100-line will be missing on one of the 3 graphs, or sometimes it looks correct on all of them.

For example, when I look at it in Chrome 37.0.2062.120 on Ubuntu, I see that issue with the first graph only. In Firefox 27.0.1, I see the issue with the second graph only. I had coworkers report seeing the issue with the third graph in some browsers, and didn't see the issue on any of them in other browsers.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 2):

You only have so many pixels to play with in a chart's height as you decrease it. While using Chrome I am not able to make the markers disappear I do see the line width decreasing on the 249 px chart. Depending on the users screen resolution and rendering engine the aliasing could be more/less.

Why don't you pick a single height?

Comment: Maybe my post was misleading. The issue is not that I have a variable height, the issue is that there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to pick one height and have the graph render correctly in all browsers.

Comment: You are going to need to determine a base browser to test in and then increase your test pool. IE/Chrome/FF/Safari/etc all have their own little wriggles.

Comment: Firefox/Safari/Chrome on osx displays every of them properly (the same line width, all markers visible). I would try to play around with [shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering). I'm pretty sure there used to be bug in Chrome with rendering 1-2px paths.